# Save documents from OpenShift Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, openshift

I have a `scalable app` in `OpenShift` with `MongoDb2.2` ad `NodeJs0.10`,

Since i can't use `Cartridge rockmongo-1.1` because it cannot be embedded in scalable app,

How can i get my db'documents and do a `Backup` and `Restore` with `ssh` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you use the RHC command line tools.

You have two ways to get to your data:

1) You can ssh into your gear (as a shortcut you can do *rhc ssh {app-name}*). Then you can do the dump and restore at the console. Remember, you only have write permissions to the ~/app-root/data and /tmp directory so make sure to put your output there. Then you can scp your files back and forth.

2) You can you*rhc port forward* to port forward you MongoDB terminal and commands to you local machine. You will still need the MongoDB username and password we assigned to your instance on creation.